# Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 0, current count = 1

Tags: c#, sql-server, mvc, stored-procedure

Buenas tengo este procedure pero me esta arrojando el sgte mensaje de error.

> Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of
> BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 0, current count = 1

Este es el procedure está hecho en SQLServer. Según yo estoy haciendo una inserción de un producto y si el código ya existe me manda al catch personalizando la respuesta de salida.

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[RegProductos](
@CodigoProducto varchar(10),
@IdCategoria Int,
@Nombre varchar(100),
@TipoProducto varchar(8),
@Descripcion varchar(100),
@Precio Decimal(18,5),
@Cantidad Decimal(18,5),
@Stock Decimal(18,5),
@UnidadMedida varchar(10),
@IdProveedor int,
@NombreProveedor varchar(100),
@IdRestaurante int,
@Activo bit,
@UsuarioRegistro varchar(100),
@IdProducto int output,
@Resultado bit output,
@Message VarChar(250) output  
)
as
begin
    BEGIN TRY
 BEGIN TRANSACTION  
    DECLARE @Id int;
    if (@IdProveedor != 0)
        begin
        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM InvProducto WHERE CodigoProducto = @CodigoProducto)
            begin
                insert into InvProducto(CodigoProducto,IdCategoria,TipoProducto,Nombre,Descripcion,Precio,Cantidad,Stock,UnidadMedida,IdProveedor,IdRestaurante,Activo,FechaRegistro,UsuarioRegistro) values (
                @CodigoProducto,@IdCategoria,@TipoProducto,@Nombre,@Descripcion,@Precio,@Cantidad,@Stock,@UnidadMedida,@IdProveedor,@IdRestaurante,@Activo,GetDate(),@UsuarioRegistro)

                select @IdProducto = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
                
                SET @Resultado = 1
                COMMIT    
            end
        end
    else
        begin
            insert into invProveedor(Nombre,IdRestaurante,Activo,FechaRegistro,UsuarioRegistro) values(
            UPPER(@NombreProveedor),@IdRestaurante,1,GETDATE(),@UsuarioRegistro)

            set @Id  = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

            insert into InvProducto(CodigoProducto,IdCategoria,TipoProducto,Nombre,Descripcion,Precio,Cantidad,Stock,UnidadMedida,IdProveedor,IdRestaurante,Activo,FechaRegistro,UsuarioRegistro) values (
                @CodigoProducto,@IdCategoria,@TipoProducto,@Nombre,@Descripcion,@Precio,@Cantidad,@Stock,@UnidadMedida,@Id,@IdRestaurante,@Activo,GetDate(),@UsuarioRegistro)
            SET @Resultado = 1
            
            select @IdProducto = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
            COMMIT    
        end
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SET @Resultado = 0;
        SET @IdProducto = 0;
        SET @Message = (select ERROR_MESSAGE() as Error);     
        
        if (select ERROR_NUMBER()) = 2627
        begin
            SET @Message = 'El código del producto ya existe'; 
        end
        if (select ERROR_NUMBER()) = 201
        begin
            SET @Message = 'El código del producto ya existe'; 
        end
        IF @@tranCount > 0                        
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

    END CATCH
end
```

No puedo encontrar el error acerca de esto, agradeceria una explicación.

Comment: No es `@TranCount`  sino `@@TRANCOUNT `

Comment: Encontre el error, segun el mensaje que arroja es que estoy finalizando el procedure dejando abierto `BEGIN TRAN` y no hacer el `COMMIT` o `ROLLBACK` correspondiente en todas las salidas del bloque de código.

Comment: Erick Sería bueno que publicaras la solución como respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontre el error, segun el mensaje que arroja es que estoy finalizando el procedure dejando abierto BEGIN TRAN y no hacer el COMMIT o ROLLBACK correspondiente en todas las salidas del bloque de código.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM InvProducto WHERE CodigoProducto = @CodigoProducto)
    begin
       insert into InvProducto(CodigoProducto,IdCategoria,TipoProducto,Nombre,Descripcion,Precio,Cantidad,Stock,UnidadMedida,IdProveedor,IdRestaurante,Activo,FechaRegistro,UsuarioRegistro) values (
                @CodigoProducto,@IdCategoria,@TipoProducto,@Nombre,@Descripcion,@Precio,@Cantidad,@Stock,@UnidadMedida,@IdProveedor,@IdRestaurante,@Activo,GetDate(),@UsuarioRegistro)

       select @IdProducto = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
                
       SET @Resultado = 1
       COMMIT TRANSACTION
    end
else
    begin 
       ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
       SET @Resultado = 0;
       SET @IdProducto = 0;
       SET @Message = 'El código del producto ya existe';  
    end
end
```